# Como pegar variavel js do sucess pro php

Tags: php, ajax

Como fazer a variável latitude funcionar ? Tentei assim e não está aparecendo nada!
No sucess la dentro a variavel latitude funciona, mas do lado de fora não quer funcionar, ela fica vazia. Como passar a variavel latitude pro php?
Tenho esse código abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'sigilo.com.br/$ip',
        type:'get',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(res) {
                latitude = res.lat;
                longitude = res.long;
                cidade = res.city;
                Pais  = res.country


        }

    });

    </script>
<?php
$variavelphp = "<script>document.write(latitude)</script>";
echo $variavelphp;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que a variável ainda não existe quando o PHP renderiza a página. Se você olhar no console, verá um erro tipo:

> latitude is not defined.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'sigilo.com.br/$ip',
    type:'get',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(res) {

        // AQUI A VARIÁVEL É DEFINIDA
        // MAS É TARDE DEMAIS,
        // POIS O PHP JÁ FOI PROCESSADO

        latitude = res.lat;
        longitude = res.long;
        cidade = res.city;
        Pais  = res.country
    }

});
```

A variável só terá valor no retorno do Ajax, e isso só ocorrerá após o carregamento da página, quando o PHP já fez a parte dele. E nem você conseguirá alterar de forma dinâmica essa variável `$variavelphp` porque ela foi criada no *back-end*.

Comment: ai nao entendi , :(

Comment: @DenyProgramadorBom Quando o PHP carrega a página, a variável `latitude` não existe. Após o carregamento da página, o Ajax vai ser executado e criar a variável, mas aí já era, porque o PHP já fez a parte dele que era apenas carregar a página.

Comment: Oxenteee o javascript não executa enquanto carrega junto com o php?

Comment: @DenyProgramadorBom O Ajax não retorna o valor junto com o carregamento da página, somente após.

Comment: @DenyProgramadorBom Quando a página é carregada, o Ajax ainda vai buscar na página `sigilo.com.br/$ip` o valor para definir a variável `latitude`.

Comment: Mais o javascript carrega junto com o php né

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer direto no php

```
// Pegue o valor via URL
$json = file_get_contents('sigilo.com.br/ip');

// Transforme o resultado em um objeto JSON
$obj = json_decode($json);

// Ou transforme o resultado em um array
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

// Acesse o valor no objeto
$variavelphp = $obj->lat;

// Ou no array
$variavelphp = $arr['lat'];
echo $variavelphp;
```